# Is $xRy$ iff $x$ and $y$ were born less than one week apart reflexive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

So I asked this question before without getting a solid answer. I went and studied a bit more about binary relations and reflexive relations. I understand the theory, but am unsure about whether my application of the the theory is correct in my answers.

For the Question below:

Let $A$ be the set of all people who have ever lived. For $x$,$y$∈$A$, $xRy$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ were born less than one week apart. Determine:

(i) Whether or not the relation $R$ is reflexive;

I have stated that, $xRy$ is NOT reflexive, as for the relation $xRy$,  ∀ $x∈A$ is not equal ∀ $y∈A$

is this right? if not could someone tell me why not and possibly show me how to get the right answer for this particular question.

Comment: Archimedes and Archimedes were born less than a week apart. So were John Lennon and John Lennon. And so on.

Comment: oh ok, but thats taking the relation xRx, I assumed the question asked for xRy, so Archimedes wasn't born a week apart from John Lennon (x and y being different people)

Comment: as you can see I'm really not fully comprehending this question....

Comment: You are maybe confusing *reflexive* ($xRx$) with *symmetric* (if $xRy$ then $yRx$). The relation born less than a week apart is also symmetric, but that is not what is being asked.

Comment: so reflexivity only ever compares a set to itself?

Comment: Reflexivity only has to do with whether an object has the relationship $R$ with itself.

Comment: ah thank you, I was getting confused with the question stating xRy, m lecturers notes are all handwritten and look like hieroglyphics so finding any explanation there is useless, just need to study up more on relations online

Comment: We have here some technical terms, whose meaning you are being asked to learn. After the words have been internalized, you will not find this sort of question difficult.

Comment: as a follow up, for this question is it true to state that the relation is not antisymmetric as ($xRy$ $ AND $ $yRx$) does not imply $x==y$

Comment: so it would be like "$John$ and $Jack$ were born less than a week apart, $Jack$ and $John$ were born less than a week apart, but $John$ $!=$  $Jack$

Comment: Yes, rhar is correct. It is perfectly possible to have $xRy$ and $yRx$ without having $x=y$.

Comment: One last question, would it be true to say that the set relation is not transitive, as $John$ was born less than a week apart from $Jack$ who was born less than a week apart from $James$, does not imply that $John$ was born less than a week away from $James$? Or would it be transitive, as the relation between $John$ and $Jack$ is the same as the relation between $Jack$ and $James$?

Comment: It is not transitive, You can have A and B be less than 1 week apart, and B and C less than 1 week apart, but A and C more than 1 week apart. They could have been born, respectively, Jan 1 2000, Jan 6 2000, and Jan 11 2000.

Comment: thanks that was my logic in thinking as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is reflexive!

$xRx$ is: are you born less than one week apart... from yourself? But of course.

Comment: ok so it might be I'm misunderstanding of the phrasing of the question, why did you take the relation xRx, when the question asks for the relation xRy?

Comment: @roughosing because reflexivity only asks about $xRx$. $R$ is the relation.

Comment: oh, so would i have to state that $xRx$ is reflexive, and $yRy$ is reflxive, or just state the one?

Comment: It's the same statement. When you write $x$, you mean $\forall x$